# $G$ be a group of order $p^n$ and $H$ be any subgroup of $G$; then does there exist $x \in G\setminus H$ , such that $xH=Hx$?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a group of order $p^n$ , where $p$ is a prime and $n \in\mathbb N$ and $H$ be any subgroup of $G$; then does there exist $x \in G\setminus H$ , such that $xH=Hx$ ?

Comment: Every finite $p$-group is nilpotent. In particular, in nilpotent groups "normalizers grow". This means that
$$N_G(H) \supsetneq H$$ So the answer to your question is yes.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

If $Z(G)\not\subseteq H$, then letting $x\in Z(G)$ will satisfy the problem.

If $Z(G)\subseteq H$, then we take quotient by $Z(G)$ and apply induction. Suppose $x\mapsto \bar{x}$ denotes the quotient map. Then, by the induction hypothesis, there is $\bar{x}\in\bar{G}\backslash\bar{H}$ such that $\overline{xH}=\overline{Hx}$. It is easy to conclude $xH=Hx$ from here.

Comment: ADD: You should verify that the center of a p-group is nontrivial, so that you can actually apply the induction hypothesis.